# 64-bit LiveCD won't boot... 32-bit does

Tags: 11.10, live-cd, installation, live-usb

I've been using 11.10 32-bit for a while, and found some spare DIMMs lying around. I put them in my machine and it detected them fine, but obviously 32-bit Ubuntu couldn't.

Rather than re-install I tried to use the PAE kernel but this toasted my machine.

So I decided to just go ahead and install 64-bit version. Trouble is the LiveCD (or USB) won't boot. It loads the desktop and mouse icon before taking me to a high-res text screen that says:

```
Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [ OK ]
```

It then hangs here.

If I use the 32-bit version it loads the desktop fine!

What can I do?

My Hardware:

- Asus P5Q Pro
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 @ 2.40GHz x4
- GeForce 9600GT
- 4x 1GB DDR2 RAM Modules

Comment: I have a similar hardware except for my video card ( it's an ATI ) and all runs just fine with several Ubuntu versions, both 32 and 64 bit, i can suggest to re-download the iso and check for MD5 hashing checksum https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: I checked the MDS checksums on both the files I downloaded and they are correct...

Comment: I just tried the Alternate AMD64 iso (checked MD5 again and OK) and it fails too :( - Maybe I'll have to try and old installer and upgrade!

Comment: really strange, probably it's a bug, i don't know what to say, try to boot an image from this iso files https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the menu when booting, I selected Memory Test and immediately, it showed error after error for one of my modules (thankfully the smallest one, only 1GB).

Removed it and the LiveCD/USB boot first time without a hitch!

If you have a similar issue... try testing the memory too!